# Disability discrimination - channels and asymmetry

Tags: united-kingdom, disabilities

So, I was recently experiencing a situation where I couldn't seem to get a satisfactory experience using an organization's on-line customer service channel.

The only alternative presented to me at the moment is to use their phone line. I have an intense dislike of using the phone<sup>1</sup>. They also don't seem to offer any generally visible "customer complaints" email address<sup>2</sup>.

This got me wondering - a great many organizations seem to offer "easy sign up, difficult or impossible cancellation" scenarios. Where the "undo" action is available over fewer/a single channel. Is there anything in UK law that *should* make this illegal, considering people with disabilities who may not have equal access to all channels? Or any legal cases that try to look into this?

---

<sup>1</sup>And I have a disability that I would easily be able to say that having to use this would be an additional hardship for me, but I want to ask the general question.

<sup>2</sup>I presume I'll be able to find some suitable access via a chat tomorrow when I want to raise my complaint - I need to cool off

Comment: Mere "intense dislike" is not a disability that needs be accommodated. If you want to ask about the situation where using a phone is actually excessively difficult due to recognised disability, just make it so - it is otherwise pointlessly confusing to include a definite **non-**disability situation when titled and discussing a disability situation.